# How to update data when compare to data time with current time in Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using date time to compareTo 2 date time in spring. I have one date has set before and compare with current time..

example i have time following as:

```
    dataDateSystem = 03/08/2021 12:15
    scheduled      = 03-08-2021 17:00
```

my code:

```
    smsBrandingList = smsService.selectListSMSBranding(params);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();

    String dataDateSystem = formatter.format(date);

    System.out.println(dataDateSystem);

    for(int i=0 ; i< smsBrandingList.size() ; i++) {

        System.out.println(smsBrandingList.get(i).get("scheduled"));

        String smsSendStatusScheduled = (String) smsBrandingList.get(i).get("scheduled");

        int result = dataDateSystem.compareTo(smsSendStatusScheduled);
        System.out.println(result);

        
            smsService.insertOrUpdateStatusOfSendSMS(SMSConstant.STATUS_SENT);
            logger.info("CompareTo data and Date -> {1}" + SMSConstant.STATUS_SENT);
        
        
    }
    smsBrandingList = smsService.selectListSMSBranding(params);
    System.out.println(smsBrandingList);
```

my service:

```
@Override
 public void insertOrUpdateStatusOfSendSMS(String status) {
     smsBrandingListMapper.insertOrUpdateStatusOfSendSMS(status);
 }
```

my query:

```
<update id="insertOrUpdateStatusOfSendSMS" parameterType="Map">
   UPDATE MSC0053M
         SET STATUS = #{status}
         <!--  WHERE SMS_ID = #{smsId} -->
</update>
```

when i compared `dataDateSystem` with `smsSendStatusScheduled`, if `dataDateSystem` > `smsSendStatusScheduled` will return status `sent` or if `dataDateSystem` < `smsSendStatusScheduled` it will return status `waiting` by `insertOrUpdateStatusOfSendSMS` method

my code there are not got exceptions but it got result not as expected, that is it updated all rows.

and my expectations is it only update status of row when compare `dataDateSystem` and `smsSendStatusScheduled`

How can i fix the problem ?

Comment: You are comparing strings not dates. Parse to dates and compare those instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum: could you answer me ?

Answer (score 0):

## Parse as `LocalDateTime`

Parse your strings into [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object.

That class implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) with a [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#compareTo(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)) method, so objects of that class know how to sort themselves.

To parse, define a formatting pattern to match your input strings.

```java
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

As mentioned, these objects carry a `compareTo` method. They also have convenient comparisons methods: [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)), [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isEqual(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)), and [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)).

In my own code, I would stick to *before-equal-after* ordering of the tests. But here is example code using your ordering.

```java
if ( x.isEqual( y ) ) {
    // …
} else if ( x.isAfter( y ) ) {
    // …
} else if ( x.isBefore( y ) ) {
    // …
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException( "Reached impossible point while comparing x & y dates. Message # 7bacb0c6-fc7b-4819-a776-1f55b253f0aa." );
}
```

Notice how the last `else` case throws an exception because this point in the code should never be reached, it should be impossible for that code to ever execute. Those of us who practice [defensive-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) would include such an impossible case, because it just might become possible if anyone makes a mistake while editing the other `if` tests. Compare this to the code in your Question where you treat that last `else`, a supposedly impossible situation, as a normal situation. This makes your code confusing or misleading to read, so I suggest doing something else.

Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. Those terrible classes are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

These topics have been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

Comment: Hi@Basil Bourque: how to can get current time of system with LocalDateTime  with format: dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm ?